# Nodejs wait for socket and then respond to http request

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, asynchronous

I have a NodeJS code where, basically this is what happens:

HTTP request (app.get) -> Send a request to a low level socket(using net.Socket()) -> Get response from socket -> res.send(response from socket)

This doesn't work because the net.Socket() uses async functions and events (`client.on("data", callback)`).

I tried something like this:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
   client.connect("localhost", 420, function(){
      client.write("example data");
   });
   client.on("data", function(data){
       client.destroy();
       res.send(data);
});
});
```

But it doesn't work because it says I am re-sending the headers (the res object won't change since the function is an event, not a sync function).

Any ideas? Or a library for sync socket requests? I have tried the following:

- Synket
- sync-socket
- netlinkwrapper

And they don't work.

---

Edit: I am trying something like this:

```
async function sendData(client, res){
  client.on('data', function(data){
    console.log("Got data!");
    res.send(""+data);
    res.end();
    console.log("Sent data!");
    client.destroy();
    console.log("Killed connection");
    return;
  });
}

app.get("/", function(req, res){
   var body = req.query;

client.connect(420, "localhost", function(){
      client.write("some random data");
      console.log("Connected & Data sent!");
      sendData(client, res);
   });
});
```

It works the first time I try to access the page, but the second time the app crashes and I get this error:

```
_http_outgoing.js:489
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Answer (score 0):

`client` triggles `data` event multiple times.

```
`app.get("/", function(req, res){
   client.connect("localhost", 420, function(){
      client.write("example data");
   });
   client.pipe(res);
});
});
`
```

Comment: It doesn't work.
1. It doesn't end the res.
2. It's async.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that, each time a request comes to that endpoint, a new subscription has been registered by calling the `client.on('eventName', cb)`. So, calls starting from the second one will trigger multiples of those registrations and will cause that header error.

So, a workaround for that:

```
socket.on('event', (packet) => {
    socket.removeAllListeners('event')
    res.json({ packet });
});
```

That would do the trick but I'm not sure if it's a bad practice to continuously add/remove the same event.

**Edit**

Found a better way. `once` will ensure that registered event only will run once, just as we want:

```
socket.once('event', (packet) => {
    res.json({ packet });
});
```